# Why will my field calculator python function always return Null if any inputs are Null?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I've written a simple python function that outputs a list based on yes/no fields. It appends a word to a list if it has a "yes" in another column then writes the list, formatted according to the number of values in it.

It looks like this:

```
def proctype(prestm, presdm, postm, posdm, beam, wem):


    mylist = []
    if prestm == 'YES':
        mylist.append("PreSTM")
    if presdm == 'YES':
        mylist.append("PreSDM")
    if postm == 'YES':
        mylist.append("PoSTM")
    if posdm == 'YES':
        mylist.append("PoSDM")
    if beam == 'YES':
        mylist.append("Beam")
    if wem == 'YES':
        mylist.append("WEM")


    if len(mylist) == 1:
        return mylist[0]
    if len(mylist) == 2:
        return mylist [0] + " and " + mylist[1]     
    if len(mylist) == 3:
        return mylist[0] + ", " + mylist[1] + " and " + mylist[2]
    if len(mylist) == 4:
        return mylist[0] + ", " + mylist[1] + ", " + mylist[2] + " and " + mylist[3]
    if len(mylist) == 5:
        return mylist[0] + ", " + mylist[1] + ", " + mylist[2] + ", " + mylist[3] + " and " + mylist[4]
    if len(mylist) == 6:
        return mylist[0] + ", " + mylist[1] + ", " + mylist[2] + ", " + mylist[3] + ", " + mylist[4] + " and " + mylist[5]
```

This works exactly as I want it to if the fields its looking at are 'yes' and 'no', but if there are any Null values in the six input fields the output will always be null.

Does anyone know why this is? Can the field calculator not handle Null inputs, or does the list.append have a problem with Null values?

I've tried setting the values to a number if theyre null like this:

```
if prestm is None:
    prestm = 1
```

But that doesn't help.

EDIT: This problem only occurs when the inputs are from other fields in the table. inputing "" works but

> proctype( !PRESTM!, !PRESDM!, !POSTM! , !POSDM! , !BEAM_MIGRATION! ,
>   !WEM_RTM! )

doesnt.

**EDIT 2:** The problem is not with my code it is with passing in other attributes as parameters where any of them are Null

```
def testing(prestm, presdm, postm, posdm, beam, wem):
    return "test ok"
```

Returns "test ok" when all of the fields are populated but null

if any of the input fields are Null

Comment: Your code worked for me... I tried setting prestm = None and prestm = "" the function returned as expected.

Comment: I've just tried the same - typing the parameters manually and it works. The problem therefore must be with the field calculator reading columns which are Null. 

proctype( !PRESTM!, !PRESDM!, !POSTM! , !POSDM! , !BEAM_MIGRATION! , !WEM_RTM! ) is what doesn't work

Comment: May or may not end up being relevant, but, it may be useful to know what your data source is (are you trying to do this with a File GDB, Personal GDB, SQL Server 2008R2 SDE, etc...)?

Comment: @John Its in an oracle SDE geodatabase. Polygon Feature Class

Comment: ...and I've just tried exporting a feature to a FGDB and got the same result

Comment: Can you print out types of values when returning them using `type(var)`?

Comment: Whether this solves the problem or not, remove the space between mylist and [0] for the statement that reads:  return mylist [0] + " and " + mylist[1]

Comment: Add the clause len(mylist) == 0: and return some value to tell you all values were not 'Yes'.  If the return value is Null the calculation must have an error.  If it is the value you specified for the empty list you know the list was never populated.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst good idea. It appears that I have an error.

Comment: Now that you know there is an error, the most probable error is a type error.  If any field value is actually numeric, and not text, then the list will never be populated, because the statement:  if prestm == 'YES': throws a type error and instead needs to be:  if prestm == 1:  If the field has a domain then the value "YES" could be a domain representation of a numeric code.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst It works though if there are no Null values. Can it be that there is a type error only affecting null? 
I've just tried adding 'if prestm is None:
  prestm = "NO"' for each input, and it still always outputs <null> if any inputs are <null>. I've even tried setting the nulls to yes and that doesnt work. 

It seems like it just refuses to read any further if it seems any null values in the inputs

Comment: I've determined that its not an error in my code its passing through any null values I've tried a function: def testing(prestm, presdm, postm, posdm, beam, wem):
 return "test ok". This still doesnt work if any of the fields its looking at are <Null>

Comment: Does it produce Null for some records and a correct value for other records?  Or does it just produce Null for everything as soon as the first Null value is encountered?  Frankly, it should not matter.  Nulls can be passed to python equations from fields unless the field name is wrong in the input.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst It will run on the whole feature class without any errors. But only the rows where there are no null values produce a value in the column in writing to.

This is why its strange because its clearly working for the other rows

Comment: A workaround is to change all the Nulls to "unknown" but its bizarre that nothing else works

Comment: Do a Select By Attribute of PRESTM is NULL (assuming PRESTM has Null values).  Does it select records?  If not something is corrupt.  Why let users retain Null values anyway?  Is Null really valid?  Why not assign all Nulls to "FIX".  Then set a default value of "FIX" so that no new records ever have a Null value.  "FIX" would be easy to select and force a correct assignment of "YES" or "NO".  Nulls are just a pain in the *** if you don't really ever need them in your data and there are alternative ways to represent Null values in data that remove the complications they create.